# Can't transfer data between Bluetooth on Raspberry Pi Pico w and Raspberry Pi Zero 2w

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi-pico

I try to connect the two devices via Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) and transfer data between them, but after the two devices connect to each other, they immediately disconnect. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Raspberry Pi Pico W code (server):

```
import sys
import aioble
import bluetooth
import machine
import uasyncio as asyncio
from micropython import const


def uid():
    """ Return the unique id of the device as a string """
    return "{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(
        *machine.unique_id())


MANUFACTURER_ID = const(0x02A29)
MODEL_NUMBER_ID = const(0x2A24)
SERIAL_NUMBER_ID = const(0x2A25)
HARDWARE_REVISION_ID = const(0x2A26)
BLE_VERSION_ID = const(0x2A28)

led = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)

_DEVICE_INFO_UUID = bluetooth.UUID(0x180A) # Device Information
_GENERIC = bluetooth.UUID(0x1848)
_BUTTON_UUID = bluetooth.UUID(0x2A6E)
                              
_BLE_APPEARANCE_GENERIC_REMOTE_CONTROL = const(384)

ADV_INTERVAL_MS = 250_000

device_info = aioble.Service(_DEVICE_INFO_UUID)
                              
connection = None

# Create Characteristic for device info
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(MANUFACTURER_ID), read=True, initial="KevsRobots.com")
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(MODEL_NUMBER_ID), read=True, initial="1.0")
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(SERIAL_NUMBER_ID), read=True, initial=uid())
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(HARDWARE_REVISION_ID), read=True, initial=sys.version)
aioble.Characteristic(device_info, bluetooth.UUID(BLE_VERSION_ID), read=True, initial="1.0")

remote_service = aioble.Service(_GENERIC)

button_characteristic = aioble.Characteristic(remote_service, _BUTTON_UUID, read=True, notify=True)

print("Registering services")

aioble.register_services(remote_service, device_info)

connected = False

async def remote_task():
    """ Task to handle remote control """
    while True:
        if not connected:
            print("Not Connected")
            await asyncio.sleep_ms(1000)
            continue
        button_characteristic.write(b"data")
        button_characteristic.notify(connection, b"data")
        await asyncio.sleep_ms(10)

async def peripheral_task():
    """ Task to handle peripheral """
    global connected, connection
    while True:
        connected = False
        connection = await aioble.advertise(ADV_INTERVAL_MS,
                                            name="KevsRobots",
                                            appearance=_BLE_APPEARANCE_GENERIC_REMOTE_CONTROL,
                                            services=[_GENERIC])
        print("Connection from", connection.device)
        connected = True
        print("connected")
        await connection.disconnected()
        print("disconnected")


async def main():
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(peripheral_task()),
        asyncio.create_task(remote_task())
        ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Raspberry Pi Zero 2W code (client):

```
import pygatt

CHARACTERISTIC = "00002a6e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"


def connect_to_ble_device(device_address):
    print('start')
    adapter = pygatt.GATTToolBackend()
    adapter.start()
    try:
        print("Connecting to BLE device with address: {}".format(device_address))
        device = adapter.connect(device_address)
        while True:
            value = device.char_read(CHARACTERISTIC, timeout=10)
            print('value is', value)
    finally:
        adapter.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_ble_device('28:CD:C1:0C:39:65')      # Pico MAC Address
```

After running the code I can see the Zero has successfully connected to the Pico (the Pico's console shows info about the connection), but I get `pygatt.exceptions.NotificationTimeout: None` from the zero.

Comment: You might want to use a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to test and debug your BLE peripheral (server on pico) before going on to develop the central device on the Zero.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I used the software you mentioned to test the Pico code, and when I use the app I manage to connect to Pico without a problem and for an unlimited time, and I receive the data it sends on my phone.  So it's probably not a server-side problem.